# How can I iterate over a dict which is indexed by a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have an iteration like:

```
for index in my_dict:
   print index.keys()
```

Is `index` possible to be a dictionary in this case? If possible, could you please give me an example of what `my_dict` will look like?

Comment: Are you asking, is it possible to have nested dictionaries? If so, yes

Comment: But the nested dictionaries will be *values*, and you're iterating over the *keys* (which **cannot** be dictionaries). As written, that code will not work.

Comment: Per document: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries keys of dictionary need to be immutable type, so answer is no, 'index' in this case can not be a dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index` cannot be a `dict` as dictionary keys must be *hashable* types. Since dictionaries are themselves not *hashable*, they can not serve as keys to another dictionary.

```
for index in my_dict
```

iterates over the dictionary keys and will yield the same result as

```
for index in my_dict.keys()
```

You can however have a dictionary nested as a value of another dictionary:

```
{'parent': {'nested': 'some value'}}
#          ^   nested dictionary  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are an unhashable type in Python so another dictionary cannot be used for as a key (or index) to a parent dictionary but it can be used as a value.

That dictionary would look something like this:

```
my_dict = {'example': {'key': 0}}
```

And if you wanted to loop over it and select the dictionaries rather than the keys the code would look something like this:

```
for key in my_dict:
    print(my_dict[key].keys())
```

Which if you've been following along with the example should just output `['key']`.

It wasn't part of your question but I'd recommend using a tuple for the kind of data storage and access you want, and if you'd like I can show you how to do that as well.